# Can we fix delimited “|” sign

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can we fix delimited | sign, every time I don’t want run wizard for Text to Columns, scenario is excel file will be same user will copy from text file with | sign & past in excel then excel will not ask to make Text to Columns, excel will deduct “|” sign & make column automatically,

Comment: You need a Macro or VBA code

Answer (score 0):

1. In Microsoft Windows, click the *Start* button, and then click *Control Panel*.
2. Open the dialog box for changing Regional and Language settings.
3. look for the **List separator** box, it can be inside the *Additional Settings* button.

[image]

4. Change it to `|`.
5. Click OK twice.

From now on, any .csv file with separator `|`can be opened directly.